# TS2345 error, but the arguments should be ok?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mxgraph

So i have this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(bounds: any, fill: any, stroke: any, strokewidth: any) => mxShape' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any) => mxShape'. 
Type '(bounds: any, fill: any, stroke: any, strokewidth: any) => mxShape' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): mxShape'.
```

In my understanding, `new (...args: any): mxShape` should be sufficient for the given, but Typescript says, its not fitting for it. Why?

This how my MxHeaderShape is built:

```
     function MxHeaderFooterShape(bounds, fill, stroke, strokewidth) : mxShape{
        let val = mxShape.call(this);
        this.bounds = bounds;
        this.fill = fill;
        this.stroke = stroke;
        this.strokewidth = (strokewidth != null) ? strokewidth : 1;
        return val;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to create a `MxHeaderFooterShape` class that extends `mxShape`.
Assuming you are using [typed-mxgraph](https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph), you can use this way of doing

```js
import mx from './mxgraph'; // mxGraphExportObject returned by the mxgraph factory function
import type { mxRectangle } from 'mxgraph';


class CustomMxShape extends mx.mxShape {

  constructor(bounds: mxRectangle, fill: string, stroke: string, strokewidth?: number) {
    super(bounds, fill, stroke, strokewidth);
  }

}
```

You can also check this demo: https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph-example-bundled-with-webpack/blob/7f0bf757aedb12cec84d86b4c4e4cbcb0f7a8147/src/app/custom-shapes.ts